# How to make a parametrized SQL Query on Classic ASP?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

Can someone show me the simplest way of perform a parametrized SQL query using Classic ASP in VBscript?

A compilable example would be best.

Comment: Are you referring to a parameterized SQL query?

Comment: yes. going to update the question to clarify. thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the adodb.command object.

```
with createobject("adodb.command")
    .activeConnection = application("connectionstring")
    .commandText = "select * from sometable where id=?"
    set rs = .execute( ,array(123))
end with
```

I would also advise to use a custom db access object instead of using adodb directly. This allows you to build a nicer api, improves testability and add hooks for debuging/logging/profiling. Secondly you can add request scoped transactions with implicit rollback's on errors using the class_terminiate event. Oure db access object offers the following query api

```
call db.execute("update some_table set column=? where id=?", array(value, id))
set rs = db.fetch_rs("select * from some_table where id=?", array(id))
count = db.fetch_scalar("select count(*) from some_table where column > ?", array(value))
```

Comment: very elegant and minimal vbscript - I like it!

Comment: This doesn't work if the column is numeric and the value is null. Is there a way for this to work without using ADODB.Command.CreateParameter?

Comment: It will work if you call objCommand.Parameters.Refresh after setting the CommandText property.
Empty elements in the array have to be replaced with Null.

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you are referring to a parameterized SQL Query. If this is the case, then the VBScript code would look something like this:

```
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "connectionstring"
SET cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = adoCon
cmd.CommandType= adCmdStoredProc 
cmd.CommandText = "GetCustomerByFirstName" 

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FirstName",adVarchar,adParamInput,50,"John")    

Set Rec = cmd.Execute()
While NOT Rec.EOF
  'code to iterate through the recordset
  Rec.MoveNext
End While
```

**UPDATE:** You need to include the ADOVBS.inc file for the constants to be recognized.

Here's a link: [ADOVBS.inc](http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/adovbs/adovbs.inc.txt)

Comment: do I need to include some file to get ASP to recognize adVarchar and adParamInput constants?

Comment: Yes. Here's a link to that file http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/adovbs/adovbs.inc.txt

Comment: This suggesstion was very helpful in stored procedures scenario

Answer (score 8):

Another option to including `adovbs.inc` is to add a reference to the following type library near the top of your ASP. Supposedly this has better performance than an include:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="ADODB Type Library" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" FILE="C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" VERSION="2.5" -->
```

[Here](http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/typelibs/default.asp) is a list of some type libraries.