# SQL/ASP - Expected: " - But it's there?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

can somebody please help me figure this out? It's giving me error after error after error and I have no idea what its problem is.

My code:

```
<%
Dim cnnSimple  ' ADO connection
Dim rstSimple  ' ADO recordset
Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
' DSNLess
cnnSimple.Open "MY CONNECTIONS STRING INFO HERE"

cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode) VALUES ('" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("first_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("last_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("hash") & "')")

rstSimple.Close
Set rstSimple = Nothing
cnnSimple.Close
Set cnnSimple = Nothing
%>
```

And the error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: ''
/thanks.asp, line 65
```

Thank you

Line 65 is:

```
cnnSimple.Execute("insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode) VALUES ('" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("first_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("last_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("hash") & "')")
```

Comment: You should be using parametrised queries. You are vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment.

Comment: Please consider the advice given in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370677/can-someone-please-tell-me-what-is-wrong-with-this-statement/3370685#3370685

Comment: I have considered all advice given in the previous answer. But at the moment security is a non-issue as it is not being released yet, and I just want to get things working. Once they are working I will worry about security. By the way, I have used all advice from previous questions and nothing has helped so far.

Comment: @j-t-s Make sure you avoid apostrophes in your test data then. They will definitely cause errors.

Comment: @Martin, thanks - I was advised to add them. Originally I didn't have any.

Comment: I just took the apostrophes out, which lead to another error.

Comment: Not sure which apostrophes you're referring to, j-t-s. Martin was talking about apostrophes in your DATA, that is, the values in Request.QueryString("last_name"), for example. You will need some apostrophes in the Execute() statement. :)

Comment: @j-t-s No I meant in the data itself. If you submit a value like O'Reilly you will get an "incorrect syntax near Reilly" error. But what was the error you got? That will at least show if you are connecting to the database successfully.

Answer (score 3):

The error implies the use of an object that hasn't been instantiated. From the code snippet given, it looks like you're attempting to close the recordset without ever instantiating it.

Do you mean to be setting rstSimple to the result of cnnSimple.Execute()?

**Edit:** Now that I've looked at the other question, what I've suggested may not be the problem. As people have pointed out, you should really clean the data in the Request object before inserting it in your string (security or no security, an apostrophe in one of those vars will kill that statement).

It's possible (my memories of VBScript are blissfully hazy) that if the Execute() statement fails, nothing will be assigned to rstSimple, and the call to rstSimple.Close() will generate the error message you're seeing.

Try setting rstSimple to a new ADODB.Recordset before calling cnnSimple.Execute() and see if that sheds any light on the issue...

Comment: I believe I do mean that. I was given this code by my hosting provider, and I just put in the querystrings because I need them there to send the query data.

Answer (score 2):

suggestion:

1. declare a string variable (myVar)
2. set the string variable = your line 65 SQL

   "insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode) VALUES ('" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("payer_email") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("first_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("last_name") & "', '" & Request.QueryString("hash") & "')"
3. response.write(myVar)

Might be easier to look at that way, to see if you have issues with quotes in your querystring variables, or whatever.  Once you're happy with it:

4. cnnSimple.Execute(myVar)

Comment: @j-t-s This would be a good first step. You need to drill down on the actual problem, and it's probably either in the way you've written the SQL string, or the values in the QueryString parameters.

Comment: I suggest that @j-t-s tries with dummy data, for example: "insert into SALT (Email, Username, FirstName, LastName, ActivationCode) VALUES ('a','a','b','c','d')" That should help sort out where the problem is coming from

Comment: @Remou -- that's a good one to try, but since @j-t-s isn't concerned about injection, using the real vars would trap cases where he's trying to enter a last name like O'Neil, etc.  Of course, parametrization would be a much better idea, as it's not only for safety, but to deal with situations like needing to insert single-quotes too -- but we won't harass @j-t-s *too* much about that...  :-P

Comment: Real vars are fine once @j-t-s gets a simler string working. At the moment there are arguments about whether it is the data types, the data content, the connections string etc that is causing the problem. My suggestion eliminates a few of the possibilities. Also, @j-t-s seems to have gone missing, so the suggestion may be of some use to someone else.

Comment: BTW The whole single quotes and security issue was raised in a previous post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370677/can-someone-please-tell-me-what-is-wrong-with-this-statement/3370685#3370685, which @j-t-s states s/he is not concerned about at the moment.