# Classic ASP: ADODB.Command output

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

Following [this other question on how to make parametrized sql query on classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770419/how-to-make-a-parametrized-sql-query-on-classic-asp), I now ask **how to debug it**?

I can write in a CommandText with it, and execute, but I can't see which SQL command I'm actually trying to run. So is there a way to check ADODB.Command's output to SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, you'll need to replace the query parameter tokens with the actual values yourself when outputting for tracing.

Comment: That'd be fine if I knew exactly how ADO was handling it, and why it's throwing me random errors instead of working! :P

Comment: @Cawas: not really sure what you mean by "exactly how it's handling it" - won't outputting the query and values tell you that?

Comment: let's say I throw it a value like this "`this's a value`". What will it do with the quote sign? More yet, I want to just get the SQL String, copy and paste to SQL Query Analyzer and see if it works.

Comment: When using parameterized queries, it does nothing with quotes as it does not need to. The values are passed in as is, no escaping needed. For getting a runnable query, you'll need to construct it yourself, quoting etc. as needed, based on data types.