# What's wrong in Classic ASP StoredProcedure insert statement

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic

Here is the classic ASP code

```
Set objCommandSec = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        With objCommandSec
            Set .ActiveConnection = MyConn
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandText = "ReportsPDFInsert"

            .CreateParameter "@StatsID", adInteger, adParamInput
            .Parameters("@StatsID") = xStats_ID

            .CreateParameter "@MemberID", adInteger, adParamInput
            .Parameters("@MemberID") = xMemberID

            .CreateParameter "@LanguageID", adInteger, adParamInput
            .Parameters("@LanguageID") = 1  '1=EN

            .CreateParameter "@PDFFilename", adVarWChar , adParamInput
            .Parameters("@PDFFilename") = PDFFilename

            .Execute
        End With
```

Here is the stored procedure code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReportsPDFInsert]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@StatsID INT
,@MemberID INT
,@LanguageID     INT
,@PDFFilename NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ReportsPDF]
       ([StatsID]
       ,MemberID
       ,[LanguageID]
       ,[PDFFilename]
       ,[DateCreated])
 VALUES
       (@StatsID
       ,@MemberID
       ,@LanguageID
       ,@PDFFilename
       ,GETDATE())

END
```

I get error as

Error number: -2147217904

Error description: Procedure 'ReportsPDFInsert' expects parameter '@StatsID', which was not supplied.

Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

If I execute the stored procedure itself, then it is working fine.  I have similar classic asp code in other page, and that works fine as well.  yes, I made sure xStats_ID does have value.  I printed just before the .Execute and I see the value.

Please somebody shed some light.  Thanks

Comment: Is `MyConn` a connection string or a connection object ?          try `.ActiveConnection = MyConn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only today I figured what was the problem.

I haven't included the **adovbs.inc** file for the constants to work.

And I don't know why it was throwing some other error message.

good reason to move away from Classic ASP [only if my boss listens]

Answer (score 2):

Try appending the parameters explicitly using something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@StatsID",adInteger, adParamInput,xStats_ID)
```

instead of `.Parameters("")`

Here is another post that might help:
[How to make a parametrized SQL Query on Classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770419/how-to-make-a-parametrized-sql-query-on-classic-asp)

Comment: Nope, the same error msg
I even tried with 0 for size parameter

Comment: Although this didn't solve the specific issue the OP had, it's good advice. It's important to note that [`CreateParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by itself only creates a `Parameter` object, _without_ appending it to the `Parameters` collection. The reason the original code works is that ADO is querying the database to automatically fill the collection (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). The `CreateParameter` calls in the OP are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the "@" in your parameter names.